# How to use sorl-thumbnail in Ajax requests

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I have a project where the [sorl-thumbnail](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/index.html) plugin is working very well in the admin however I'm having some issues implementing thumbnails in Ajax requests.

Using sorl in conjunction with [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) when I attempt to return `MyImageField.photo.url` (where `MyImageField` is of type `sorl.thumbnail.ImageField`) to a call I receive a `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` HTTP response from my development server.  All other attributes are able to return ok, and when I set up pdb and take a look in the object whose `.photo.url` attribute I am trying to return the `url` is there and valid.

Would it really be an issue to the point that sorl is making an asynchronous request to the database which is taking longer to complete than the HTTP request?

Much obliged, as always, for your input

EDIT: my images are stored on S3 which I acknowledge could cause an additional layer of difficulty if sorl is required to produce a new thumbnail for the `ImageField` object

Comment: could you please provide stacktrace for 500 error?